# How to open a webView in Windows Phone 7.x?

Tags: windows-phone-7, url, webview, external

I would like my app to have only one view.

I need this view to be an external URL.

I tried to use the webBrowser Task following the example on microsoft.

I put on my constractor :

```
WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();

webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com", UriKind.Absolute);

webBrowserTask.Show();
```

However when i press the back button instead of navigating outside the app , i am navigating to the first page which is empty...

My code looks like this :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;

//added this for push
using Microsoft.Phone.Notification;
using System.Text;

//added this to open an external URL using the WebBrowser Task
using Microsoft.Phone.Tasks;


namespace WindowsPush
{

    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {


        // Constructor
        public MainPage()
        {
            /// Holds the push channel that is created or found.
            HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel;

            // The name of our push channel.
            string channelName = "ToastSampleChannel";

            InitializeComponent();

            // Try to find the push channel.
            pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);

            // If the channel was not found, then create a new connection to the push service.
            if (pushChannel == null)
            {
                pushChannel = new HttpNotificationChannel(channelName);

                // Register for all the events before attempting to open the channel.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                //pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                pushChannel.Open();

                // Bind this new channel for toast events.
                pushChannel.BindToShellToast();

            }
            else
            {
                // The channel was already open, so just register for all the events.
                pushChannel.ChannelUriUpdated += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelUriEventArgs>(PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated);
                pushChannel.ErrorOccurred += new EventHandler<NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs>(PushChannel_ErrorOccurred);

                // Register for this notification only if you need to receive the notifications while your application is running.
                //pushChannel.ShellToastNotificationReceived += new EventHandler<NotificationEventArgs>(PushChannel_ShellToastNotificationReceived);

                // Display the URI for testing purposes. Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString());
                // MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", pushChannel.ChannelUri.ToString()));

            }

            object uniqueID;
            if (Microsoft.Phone.Info.DeviceExtendedProperties.TryGetValue("DeviceUniqueId", out uniqueID) == true)
            {
                byte[] bID = (byte[])uniqueID;
                string deviceID = Convert.ToBase64String(bID);   // There you go
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Device Unique Id is: {0}", deviceID);
            }



            //opening the external URL using webBrowserTask
            WebBrowserTask webBrowserTask = new WebBrowserTask();

            webBrowserTask.Uri = new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com", UriKind.Absolute);

            webBrowserTask.Show();


        }


        void PushChannel_ChannelUriUpdated(object sender, NotificationChannelUriEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                // Display the new URI for testing purposes.   Normally, the URI would be passed back to your web service at this point.
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.ChannelUri.ToString());
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Channel Uri is {0}", e.ChannelUri.ToString()));
            });
        }


        void PushChannel_ErrorOccurred(object sender, NotificationChannelErrorEventArgs e)
        {
            // Error handling logic for your particular application would be here.
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                MessageBox.Show(String.Format("A push notification {0} error occurred.  {1} ({2}) {3}", e.ErrorType, e.Message, e.ErrorCode, e.ErrorAdditionalData)));
        }


    }
}
```

What i need is just load an external URL on the first and only view of my app.

How could i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Add it to the main application page and handle it like you would a `WebBrowserTask`.

Comment: I am trying to use WB1.Navigate(new Uri("http://msdn.microsoft.com"));   but i get an error that WB1 doesnt exist in that context. Take into account that before i load the URL i want to run the code for enabling push notifications and registering the token on my server.

Comment: You need to add the `WebBrowser` component to the visual tree of your working page.

Comment: Could you show me how exactly to do that? Its my first C# project.

Comment: Add `<WebBrowser x:Name="WB1" />` in XAML in your `MainPage.xaml` (assuming that you are using the out-of-the-box naming).

Comment: I am getting: " The type WebBrowswer was not found verify that you are not misssing any assembly reference and that all references assemblys have been build"

Comment: It's `WebBrowser`, not WebBrowswer.

Comment: Yes thats what i meant . I write it correctly thats not the problem. I just wrote the error wrong.

Comment: To make it easy for you, drag it onto the page from the Toolbox on the right. That way the proper XML namespace will be automatically added to reference it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26661/discussion-between-donparalias-and-den-delimarsky)

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use the `WebBrowserTask` then you could close the app on returning to it by throwing an unhandled exception:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.NavigationMode == NavigationMode.Back)
    {
        throw new Exception("deliberately doing this to force the app to close");
    }
}
```

If/when you do this in Windows Phone 8 you can call `Application.Current.Terminate();` instead of throwing the exception.

Be sure to check the marketplace certification requirements for apps that just launch an external website before submitting though.

Comment: You don't need to do this if your app has only one page.